How can one run a Core ML model on macOS 10.12?
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreml mentions macOS 10.13+:

How can one run a Core ML model on macOS 10.12?

Example of a Core ML model created on Ubuntu 20.04 (tested with Python 3.10 and torch 2.3.1) with Hugging Face's Exporters lib:
git clone https://github.com/huggingface/exporters.git
cd exporters
pip install -e .
python -m exporters.coreml --model=distilbert-base-uncased exported/ --quantize=float32 


Have you tried to run above commands on 10.12?

@Philippe I don't have 10.12

After some testing, it seems it is possible to run a Core ML model on macOS 10.12. I am not aware of any workaround.
